# Remove array from JSON decode

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, json

Here's the function I'm using to grab and process a JSON input:

```
<?php
$json = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ihAapq30";
$cache_lastfm = 'BLAHBLAHDIR/'.sha1($json).'.json';

if(file_exists($cache_lastfm) && filemtime($cache_lastfm) > time() - 1000){
    // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exists, use it
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache_lastfm), true);
} else {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json), true);
    file_put_contents($cache_lastfm,json_encode($data));
}

$data = $data['recenttracks'];
foreach ($data['track'] as $track) {
    $artist = $track['artist']['#text'];
    $title = $track['name'];
    $url = $track['url'];
echo '<li><a href="', $url, '" title="', $title, '">', $artist, ' - ', $title, '</li></a>'; }
?>
```

It works perfectly.. my question is, how can I remove only the "entry" that has the:

```
        "@attr":{
           "nowplaying":"true"
        }
```

... "attribute"? Check the pastebin page to understand what I mean :)

Comment: Why not use the plain old `unset($data['recenttracks']['@attr']);`, before entering the loop?

Comment: I added it just before foreach and after $data = $data['recenttracks']; but the result is the same (entry with "nowplaying" is still present)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php
    $data = $data['recenttracks'];

    $tracks=$data['track'];

    foreach ($tracks as $index=>$track) {
        if (isset($track['@attr'])) {
            unset($tracks[$index]);
        }
    }

    foreach ($tracks as $track) {
        $artist = $track['artist']['#text'];
        $title  = $track['name'];
        $url    = $track['url'];
        echo '<li><a href="', $url, '" title="', $title, '">', $artist, ' - ', $title, '</li></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need to remove the entry only if it has "nowplaying" attribute (which is "under" @attr). How can I modify your reply with this specification? :)

Comment: Check the update, The code works fine on my part, I just changed the formatting for testing.

Comment: Oh, it's my fault.. I explained myself badly. I need the whole.. array-song (in this case) to be removed, if nowplaying is present (artist, album name, song, etc).

Comment: Check the update, the code now removes the entire song if `nowplaying` is found. I'm guessing that there's only one `nowplaying`, and if I can guess again, it's the first element every time. If that's the case, just shift the array back once. (Which is the second solution)

Comment: This is my code updated, but I'm still getting the "nowplaying" object..: http://ffio.it/json.txt
For the questions: IF nowplaying is present, it's always as first element (but it's not always present).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30945/discussion-between-dave-chen-and-multiformeingegno)